# Prevent users from disabling Outlook addin via GPO

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

How Prevent users from disabling Outlook addin via GPO  ? 
I tried this. 
http://www.safesendsoftware.com/prevent-users-from-disabling-an-add-in-in-outlook-2007-2010.html

This is working for admin login but in user login, user is able to disable plugin. How to fix this ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanisms for preventing add-ins from disabling by users.

However, you can prevent the LoadBehavior windows registry key from changing. Thus, you can be sure that your will be loaded.